# SharePoint create Folder with Graph api in Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below script to create a folder in my SharePoint library but I am getting error as Invalid request. I followed graph api as per documentation but couldn't find what is wrong in here. Any clue??

```
Function GET-Folder
{
    param($clientId, $clientSecret)
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadFolderRequestHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadFolderRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
  
    $uploadFolderRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)
    $uploadFolderRequestBody = @{
name= "NewFoldew2r"
folder = {}
} | ConvertTo-Json
    $fullname = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$($SPid)/drives/$($LibId)/root/children/"
    write-host "test"
    
    $uploadFolderResponse = Invoke-RestMethod $fullname -Method 'POST' -Headers $uploadFolderRequestHeaders -Body $uploadFolderRequestBody
    $uploadFolderResponse | ConvertTo-Json
    return $uploadFolderResponse
}
```

latest Error:

```
    2020-12-09T20:00:52.4660142Z Invoke-RestMethod : {
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4661057Z   "error": {
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4661551Z     "code": "invalidRequest",
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4662315Z     "message": "Invalid request",
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4662994Z     "innerError": {
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4663189Z       "date": "2020-12-09T20:00:52",
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4663531Z       "request-id": "99c22009-9bcb-4c3b-acb7-cd697a5040a9",
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4663926Z       "client-request-id": "99c22009-9bcb-4c3b-acb7-cd697a5040a9"
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4664153Z     }
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4664541Z   }
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4664659Z }
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4664946Z At D:\a\r1\a\_DevOpsScripts\ReleaseNoteScripts\UploadInSharePoint.ps1:103 char:28
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4665342Z + ... rResponse = Invoke-RestMethod $fullname -Method 'POST' -Headers $uplo ...
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4665666Z +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4666140Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4666515Z    eption
2020-12-09T20:00:52.4666815Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
2020-12-09T20:00:52.6029759Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-12-09T20:00:52.6394118Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

Comment: (1) I would try the above call in graph explorer and see if it works

Comment: it is used in $uploadFolderRequestBody and i am calling that in body in Invoke method

Comment: it works in graph explorer

Comment: If it works in Graph explorer then the Graph API call works. Looks like the above script is not sending the request/payload properly due to that its failing...

Comment: i logged each variables, all seem to be correct, if there was issue with request the error message would hv been different

Comment: Share the detailed error message along with timestamp, requestid that you got.

Comment: edited with latest error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are assigning different properties to folder property in the body when you use `{}` in powershell. The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) specifies the example in the JSON format where {} means an empty object.

If you print `$uploadFolderRequestBody` you would see the data as below in the folder property.

[image]

So please give the body data as below.

```
$uploadFolderRequestBody = @{
name= "NewFoldew2r"
folder = null
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"= "rename"
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

And now run the `Invoke-RestMethod`.You will be getting proper results.